# InitData for a ViewController that isn't presenting?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to `initData` for two view controllers that I don't want to present immediately.

Atm I have when a user taps a `tableViewCell` (select a group) they are presented with "chatVC" and the appropriate data is presented. In `ChatVC` the user can access two other VC, `ChatInfoVC` and `ChatInfoSettingsVC`. Is there a way to pass the right info from the tableViewCell (the group as I do when I present the `ChatVC`) to both the other VC? I'm pulling all data from Firebase.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   guard let chatVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chat") as? ChatVC else { return }
    chatVC.initData(forGroup: groupsArray[indexPath.row])
    presentDetail(chatVC)
}
```

I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically your `ChatVC` will provide the data to the viewcontrollers it presents. Therefore, you'd have to either

- hand that data from the current viewcontroller to `ChatVC` and from there further to the next two viewcontrollers, or
- fetch the detail data in `ChatVC` before presenting the two other viewcontrollers

You could also intantiiate those two viewcontrollers in `tableView(_:didSelectRow:)`, provision them with the correct data, and then store those *viewcontrollers* in two properties of your `ChatVC` -- but this seem to me somehow *strange*

Answer (score 0):

Option

A: store your VC in class property, assign it before presenting it in the didselectRow.

B: create a class property to store the indexpath of the selected one. Your VC data is inside groupsArray, u just need the indexpath to get it. Then get data, init controller, assign that data to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I m not misunderstand you, you can just store the data to the ChatVc(declare a store property in ChatVc), when you ready to present the other two ViewControllers you can easily access the data.